# MySQL - Only add to GROUP_CONCAT if count of a subquery is greater than 1

Tags: mysql

Alright, I'm trying to grab faculty team leaders and list the project IDs with which they are associated. However, I only want to add the project ID if there are at least 2 students registered in the courses associated with that project ID.

Here is what I have:

```
#Distinct students enrolled in CI
SELECT DISTINCT c.*, 

(

#Projects in ci_id order with students enrolled in the courses
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT ci_projects.ci_id SEPARATOR ', ') 

FROM `ci_projects` LEFT JOIN `ci_team_leaders` ON ci_projects.ci_id=ci_team_leaders.ci_id WHERE ci_team_leaders.username=c.username

) AS CIs

FROM `ci_projects` AS x 

INNER JOIN `ci_team_leaders` AS b ON x.ci_id=b.ci_id 
LEFT JOIN `ci_users` AS c ON b.username=c.username 
LEFT JOIN `departments` AS d ON c.dept_id=d.dept_id 
LEFT JOIN `colleges` AS e ON d.college_id=e.college_id 

WHERE x.status = 2 GROUP BY c.username HAVING (SELECT COUNT(`reg_username`) FROM `all_course_reg` AS z INNER JOIN `ci_courses` AS y ON y.    course_crn=z.reg_crn WHERE y.ci_id =ci_id AND z.reg_term = '201308') > 1
```

The query runs, but the HAVING part does not change the outcome.

OKAY I THINK I GOT IT....

```
SELECT DISTINCT `username` AS user, (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT a.ci_id SEPARATOR ', ')

FROM ci_team_leaders AS a 

LEFT JOIN `ci_courses` AS b ON a.ci_id=b.ci_id 
LEFT JOIN `all_course_reg` AS c ON b.course_crn=c.reg_crn 

WHERE a.username=user AND (SELECT COUNT(`reg_username`) FROM `all_course_reg` AS z WHERE z.`reg_crn`=c.reg_crn) > 1) AS CIs FROM `ci_team_leaders` WHERE CIs IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: You need to put the test in the subquery that lists the project IDs.

Comment: And it needs to be in a `WHERE` clause, because `HAVING` performs its test _after_ aggregation is done.

Comment: @Barmar, can you help me get rid of the NULL in the 'CIs' column? I put the code up in the original post because I couldn't format it correctly here.

Comment: Use `IFNULL` or `COALESCE` to replace `NULL` with `0`.